# Is there any way to detect two kinds of objects from an image or video using two seperate trained weight files in **YoloV5**?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov5

I had trained a weight file to detect an object and another weight file to detect another specific object using yolov5. If i want to detect both objects in a single images, can i ,like, use both weight files together? Or is there a way to combine the both trained files into a single one, without training the datasets again together?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no. There is no way to aggregate models, trained to detect different objects into one. You can sequentially detect objects by first and second model. Proper approach is to train model again with two classes.